# Sending a .docx file to the Browser with PHP

Tags: php, download

I am struggling to send a Word `.docx` file to the browser.  The Word file opens fine, if I create a link to the Word file, it also opens fine.

However when using this code:

```
            // output the file to the browser
            if ($fileToOutput) {
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileToOutput)); // this is causing the file download to fail

                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($fileToOutput) . "\"");
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($fileToOutput);
                exit;
            }
```

I get the following:

[image: Word found unreadable content]

Followed by the dreaded "Word experienced an error trying to open the file.":

[image: Word experienced an error trying to open the file]

Like I said, the Word file opens fine, and downlaods from a link fine - I only get these errors when trying to output the Word file with the above PHP code.

Where is this PHP code going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to print the doc contents to screen or open word "in browser"?

Comment: @treyBake I am trying to send the file to the browser so it can then be saved or get the browser to open the file in Word - either way results in a file that won't open when using the above PHP code.

Comment: send it how? The contents or the file? What's wrong with the usual click-download method?

Comment: @treyBake are you familiar with sending files to the browser using `header("Content-Description: File Transfer");`?  Because this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I just don't see a valid point when there are working methods, what's your actual problem here? Why do you want to use File Transfer?

Comment: @treyBake like the question states, I want to know what is wrong with the PHP code.

Comment: You are sending TWO `Content-Type` headers. Second one I dont think you need

Comment: Dont think you need this `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");`

Comment: @Jimmery I just want to know why you want it this way though? seems convoluted when you can get the same result without using file transfer or all of these headers

Comment: May be useful to send a `header("Content-Length: ". filesize(basename($fileToOutput)));`

Comment: Remove the `ob_clean`. You've output the headers and the clean discards them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried playing about with those headers, but have been unable to get any success so far - would you be able to create an answer with the correct headers I should use?  Many thanks.